# Stopping AWS EC2 instance leads to autocreation of another instance of the stopped one

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I had to stop my `m3.medium` EC2 instance from the AWS console to resize it to `m3.large`. However, after it stopped, it automatically created a new instance.

Any idea why this is happening? It caused some big troubles for me.

Comment: Are you using an autoscaling group with minimum size = 1? It may have determined that your stopped instance was unhealthy and terminated it.

Comment: Yes I think I am. How can I get my instance back which was determined as unhealthy. Since the newly started instance doesn't have any programs in it anymore :(

Comment: I don't get it why am I getting minus points. I couldn't find any answer to above described issue anywhere... why don't you rather suggest an edit if you see some mistake or a possible improvement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AutoScaling group with minimum size = 1 spun up a new instance because there were no instances in the 'running' state available to respond to requests, particularly health checks. Your instance was deemed 'unhealthy' and replaced by the ASG.

If your instance storage was ephemeral, I'm afraid it is gone forever unless you recently saved an AMI. If your [instance storage was backed by EBS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumes.html#EBSFeatures), you can recover it by attaching the EBS volume to a new instance.

In the future, consider configuring your autoscaling group's launch configuration to have everything you need ahead of time, by either bootstrapping the instance or by baking an AMI.

For 'bootstrapping' an instance:

- Create a new launch configuration with a standard AMI avaialble from Amazon.
- Add [user data](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-add-user-data) to the launch configuration to handle installation and configuration of your desired programs.

For 'baking' an AMI:

- Install your desired programs and configuration on a new EC2 instance.
- Take an image (AMI) of that EC2 instance.
- Use that image in your new launch configuration.

Manually working on an instance within an ASG and expecting the instance to persist indefinitely is dangerous, as you've just discovered.

Further Reading:

- [EC2 Documentation - AutoScaling Health Checks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/healthcheck.html)
- [EC2 Documentation - Amazon Machine Images](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html)